# PHP preg_match_all question

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a question about a regular function that is giving me grief. I have a list of items that is separated in tags. I am trying to extract everything between two particular tags (which occur multiple times). Here is a sample of the list I am parsing:

```
<ResumeResultItem_V3>
    <ResumeTitle>Johnson</ResumeTitle>
    <RecentEmployer>University of Phoenix</RecentEmployer>
    <RecentJobTitle>Advisor</RecentJobTitle>
    <RecentPay>40000</RecentPay>
</ResumeResultItem_V3>

<ResumeResultItem_V3>
    <ResumeTitle>ResumeforJake</ResumeTitle>
    <RecentEmployer>APEX</RecentEmployer>
    <RecentJobTitle>Consultant</RecentJobTitle>
    <RecentPay>66000</RecentPay>
</ResumeResultItem_V3>
```

I'm trying to get everything in between "ResumeResultItem_V3" as a blob of text, but I can't seem to get the expression right.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
$test = "(<ResumeResultItem_V3>)";
$test2 = "(<\/ResumeResultItem_V3>)";

preg_match_all("/" . $test . "(\w+)" . $test2 . "/", $xml, $matches);

foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
       echo $match;
       echo "<br /><br />";
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: As this seems to be some kind of XML data, better use a proper XML parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably better off with [`simplexml`](http://php.net/simplexml) for extracting the data here.

But to also answer the regex question. `\w+` only matches word-characters. But in this case you want it to match pretty much everything in between the delimeters, which `.*?` can be used for.

```
preg_match_all("/$test(.*?)$test2/s", $xml, $matches);
```

Only works with the `/s` modifier though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm making assuptions about your XML structure, but I really think you need an example using an XML parser, like [SimpleXML](http://php.net/SimpleXML).

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement( $file );
foreach( $xml->ResumeResultItem_V3 as $ResumeResultItem_V3 )
    echo (string)$ResumeResultItem_V3;
```

Comment: A previous answer did what I needed, but I will look into SimpleXML for future problems I run into. I am not familiar with it and haven't had time to review it. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring that you [probably ought to use an XML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), and that [PHP has one you can use](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php)...

The issue is that `\w+` matches word characters, not any character. A space and most punctuation aren't word characters, so your match fails. You need instead to match "any" character `.` for as many as there are `+`, but because you might be able to group excessively, you need a modifier to make it non-greedy, `?`. Your expression should work if you change `\w+` to `.+?` -- the any character match also requires an `s` modifier, so:

```
preg_match_all('/' . $test . '(.+?)' . $test2 . '/s', $xml, $matches);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This worked perfectly, but I changed the + for a *

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the output as an array with 1 item for each of the "text blob" matches, try this:

```
<?php
$text =
"<ResumeResultItem_V3>
    <ResumeTitle>Johnson</ResumeTitle>
    <RecentEmployer>University of Phoenix</RecentEmployer>
    <RecentJobTitle>Advisor</RecentJobTitle>
    <RecentPay>40000</RecentPay>
</ResumeResultItem_V3>

<ResumeResultItem_V3>
    <ResumeTitle>ResumeforJake</ResumeTitle>
    <RecentEmployer>APEX</RecentEmployer>
    <RecentJobTitle>Consultant</RecentJobTitle>
    <RecentPay>66000</RecentPay>
</ResumeResultItem_V3>";

$matches = preg_split("/<\/ResumeResultItem_V3>/",preg_replace("/<ResumeResultItem_V3>/","",$text));
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    <ResumeTitle>Johnson</ResumeTitle>
    <RecentEmployer>University of Phoenix</RecentEmployer>
    <RecentJobTitle>Advisor</RecentJobTitle>
    <RecentPay>40000</RecentPay>

    [1] => 


    <ResumeTitle>ResumeforJake</ResumeTitle>
    <RecentEmployer>APEX</RecentEmployer>
    <RecentJobTitle>Consultant</RecentJobTitle>
    <RecentPay>66000</RecentPay>

    [2] => 
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What a great way to look at the code. I got it working with a previous answer, but this will definitely help in the future.